# How to hide directory listing of my website (a shared hosting)?

Tags: .htaccess, directory, hide

I'm trying to hide the directory listing of my website.
I'm currently working on a website hosted by 'hostinger'.
I know that i should change something in an apache-related file, but they(hostinger) say that
i cannot change that. cuz im using a 'shared' hosting service.
so the only way is to add some code in an .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options -Indexes
```

this is my current situation in my .htaccess file. 
i've googled the info on how to do it, but it keeps listing my directory.
is there any way that i can prevent it?
or is it just impossible to accomplish with a shared hosting service?

Answer (score 3):

Try this , prevent or allow the server to display the index of the files in the folders of your web server.

You can put a .htaccess file in each of your directory with this code

> Options All -Indexes

Comment: thanks for your help. :) but i found out that i can do it thru the cpanel provided by the hosting company. but thanks anyway :)